# Reload picker on component row

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have picker view with two components. Second component has data like  "Farenheit(F)","Celcius(C)" and First component have values of F and C.
I want to reload the First component with different data according to the value selected. Second component like F & C.
So my question is "is it possible?" if yes then please reply with example or "how to do it?".

Comment: It is possible, show us your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

The way to accomplish this is below -- also, remember to call this code in the `numberOfRowsInComponent:` method.

In the `titleForRow:` method:

```
if (component == kTitleComponent)
{
    return [titleArray objectAtIndex:row];

}

else
{
    switch([pickerViewForThermo selectedRowInComponent:1])  // here you set content of component two depending on which row is selected from component 1
    {
        case 0:            // remember index starts at 0
            return [farenheitArray objectAtIndex:row];

            break;
        case 1:
            return [celciusArray objectAtIndex:row];

            break;
            //... and so on for each row in the component 1 (with index 0)
    }
}
```